# CSV with fputcsv() third parameter

Tags: php

I got a string with semi clones. I want to create a csv file.

```
$fp = fopen("abc.csv", "w");
$str = "FRUIT; STOCKS; TYPE\n lychee; B-type,A-type; instocks\n strawberry; A-type;N/A\n";

$rows = str_getcsv($str, PHP_EOL);
foreach($rows as $row) {
    $data = str_getcsv($row);
    fputcsv($fp, explode(';',$data), ";");
}
```

The `fputcsv()` doesn't seem to work correctly.

When I open the csv using EXCEL the data should be in separate columns where the semi colon (`;`) was.

```
FRUIT       TYPE           STOCKS
Lychee      B-type,A-type  instocks
Strawberry  A-type         N/A
```

EDIT:

My current output and problems are
 1. If there's are more than one words those are wrapped by a `"` (e.g. below)

```
FRUIT;STOCKS;TYPE;"COST PER ITEM"
```

2. The final output is as (when opened in excel).

   FRUIT;STOCKS;TYPE;"COST PER ITEM"
   Lychee                    "B-type   A-type";  instocks;  $54;
   Strawberry; A-type; N/A; $31;

Each `;` is in a seperate column. I want the final output to be like this

```
FRUIT       TYPE           STOCKS    COST PER ITEM
Lychee      B-type,A-type  instocks  $54
Strawberry  A-type         N/A       $31
```

Comment: fputcsv() works perfectly well, what is your actual problem? What result are you getting?

Comment: If there is more than one word in a column, then it ___should___ be wrapped in quotes..... that's what the CSV specification says should happen.... this is __not___ a problem

Comment: See the edit to my answer

Comment: Try to open the csv file in any editor not excel & post the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to use str_getcsv() to parse the whole string into lines, str_getcsv() is designed to parse a single row, not the entire content of a file/string

```
$str = "FRUIT; STOCKS; TYPE\n lychee; B-type,A-type; instocks\n strawberry; A-type;N/A\n";

$rows = explode("\n", $str);

foreach($rows as $row) {
    $data = str_getcsv($row, ';');
    $data = array_map('trim', $data);
    fputcsv($fp, $data, ';');
}
```

**EDIT**

It looks as though your MS Excel may be expecting a comma (`,`) as separator rather than a semi-colon (`;`).... so you may need to tell MS Excel this

explicitly write a `sep=;` line as the first line of your file

```
fwrite($fp, 'sep=;'.PHP_EOL);
```

before your data loop

Comment: Thank you. I tried your suggestion. Output was same as in my original code. Please see my edit.